# What to put in the dependency array in React.useMemo

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider situation:

```
const App = ({ data = [], users = [] }) => {
  const selectedId = React.memo(() => {
    return data.find((id) => id === 'someId');
  }, [data]);

  const userIds = React.memo(() => {
    return users.map(({ id }) => id);
  }, [users]);

  const finalIds = React.memo(() => {
    return userIds.find((id) => id === selectedId);
  }, []);

  return finalIds.toString();
}
```

What should I put in the dependency array in `finalIds`?

Should I:

- provide the props used by variables that are used here, e.g. - `[data, users]`
- provide the variables that are used here, e.g. - `[selectedId, userIds]`
- keep it empty

Answer (score 1):

You put any variables that you use inside the calculation. In other words, `[selectedId, userIds]`. When those variables change, you need to repeat the calculation, or `finalIds` will be stale.

If you use eslint, i'd recommend using [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks). It can spot if you're missing a variable from the dependency array and fill them in automatically.